# MVC 5 Attribute Routing - Default Action not in template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I am trying to setup attribute routing in MVC 5.  I have a route that has a default action but  the action is not in my template at all.   Here is my old route.

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "Article/{id}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "Article", action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter.Optional, path = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

This will satisfy the route of /Articles/1/test without having to use the Index for the action in the path (i.e. /Articles/Index/1/test).

I also have another method that will be caught by the default map route..../Article/Items.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to have this route setup using the new Attribute Routing in MVC 5.  The below code kind of works but I don't want to have to add a Route to each method.  I was hoping to put something at the top of the class that will satisfy all methods and I would just be adding something else to my Index method.

```
[RoutePrefix("Article")]
public class ArticleController: BaseController
{
  [Route("{id?}/{*path?}")]
  public ActionResult Index(int id, string path)
  {

  }

  [Route("Items")]
  public ActionResult Items()
  {

  }

  [Route("TestMethod")]
  public ActionResult TestMethod()
  {

  }
}
```

I was hoping for something like below.  The problem is that I am forced to put the Index in front of my path like so.../Index/1/test.

```
[RoutePrefix("Article")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class ArticleController : BaseController
{
  Route[("{id?}/{*path?}")]
  public ActionResult Index(int id, string path)
  {

  }

  public ActionResult Articles()
  {

  }

  public ActionResult TestMethod() 
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you want `Article/1/test` for your first action, and `Articles/Items` for the second one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a way you can achieve the above scenario. (you can find my comments in the code which describe the possible urls which hit the action).

Note that I used a inline constraint `int` for the 'id' route variable. This is because we want to make sure that requests like 'Article/TestMethod' does not get captured by the route 'Article/{id?}/{*path}'. Ideally you would want to have an Order property on attribute routes to order them to avoid the scenario like above, but we removed that in the last minute and didn't have time to add it back as we wanted to make sure to do it right in terms of all scenarios. (Actually you should be facing this similar issue with your pre-attribute routing changes...could you share how your pre-attribute route configuration looks like?)

We by default order the routes where we put most specific routes before generic ones. So in the current case since the one route 'Article/{id:int?}/{*path}' has a constraint, it would be placed before the generic route 'Article/{action}' and that's the reason this is working currently.

In our next release we are re-introducing the Order property which can give you more flexibility for scenarios like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("Article")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class ArticleController : Controller
{
    // GET /Article
    // GET /Article/10
    // GET /Article/10/abc/def
    [Route("{id:int?}/{*path}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id, string path)
    {
        return Content("Index:" + id + ":" + path);
    }

    // GET /Article/Articles
    public ActionResult Articles()
    {
        return Content("Articles");
    }

    // GET /Article/TestMethod
    public ActionResult TestMethod()
    {
        return Content("TestMethod");
    }
}
```